# need help understanding nonce

Tags: security

I have a question about [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). I understand it's to prevent replay attacks but what happens if the hacker somehow got the nonce and uses it before the user does?

Comment: You can't really mitigate that, can you? If someone has stolen your car, how can you stop them stealing your car?

Comment: Might as well complain that the attacker could get at your plaintext...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The purpose of a nonce is to make each request unique so that an attacker can't replay a request in a different context. It doesn't matter if the attacker gets the nonce: in fact the point is that because the data includes a nonce, it won't be useful to the attacker.

**ADDED**:

A nonce is randomly generated by the party that introduces it into the conversation. It's crucial that **an attacker cannot influence the choice of the nonce**, and sometimes that the attacker can't predict that choice. It's quite typical that each party generates at least once nonce in a run of a distributed protocol.

There are protocols where a nonce is kept secret. A session key can be both a nonce (i.e., chosen randomly by one participant) and a secret (i.e. not transmitted directly over the wire). In fact, in a well-designed protocol, a session key is often *derived* from two nonces, once coming from each party. But being secret is not a defining property of nonces.

---

Let's take the [authentication protocol on the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nonce-cnonce-uml.svg) as an example. The normal sequence of operations is:

1. The client initiates a connection to the server.
2. The server generates and sends a nonce `snonce` back to the client.
3. The client generates another nonce `cnonce`, and sends it plus a hash of its credentials, the server nonce and the client nonce (`hash(snonce + cnonce + password)`) to the server.
4. The server validates the hash and accepts or declines the logon.

Suppose Mallory (an attacker) can observe all traffic and send her own messages. If she gets hold of the nonce after step 2, she can send her own credentials to the server. This might help her cause a denial of service, but she can do that anyway if she can inject traffic. Without the client's credentials, she can't impersonate the client.

Suppose Mallory gets hold of the packet sent by the client in step 3. Since the credentials and the nonce are hashed, she can't modify the packet, she can only send it again as a whole. Again, depending on how the server implements the protocol, she might be able to cause a denial of service, but no more. (Note that this protocol requires that the server keeps track of which nonce is associated with which client and responds to that client in step 4.) The hashing operation in step 3 is what keeps Mallory from obtaining data she mustn't get (the client's password).

To see why the server nonce is there, suppose it was missing. Then Mallory would be able to obtain a packet containing `hash(cnonce + passoword)`, and she could resend it later in a separate connection and thereby impersonate the client.

The client nonce serves a similar purpose, although this is not apparent in the simplified protocol described here; in a full protocol, the “token” would include a hash of data containing this nonce, and it would participate in preventing Mallory from impersonating the server.

The client nonce also serves to prevent a password guessing attack. Suppose Mallory intercepts the server's response at step 2 and substitutes her own server nonce. If the client replied with `hash(snonce + password)`, this would make it easier for Mallory to run a mass password guessing attack: she could precompute `hash(snonce + x)` for many “easily guessable” passwords `x`, and run her attack on many clients in the hope that one has a weak password. Here the client nonce acts as a salt for the hashed password.

The client nonce also contributes to protect the client from a badly implemented server. Suppose the server did not generate a random nonce but instead a constant that Mallory could easily find by observing traffic. Then Mallory could perform the guessing attack described in the previous paragraph passively. Thus the client nonce gives the client additional protection even if the server doesn't implement the protocol correctly. Similarly, the server nonce gives the server some protection against a client that didn't generate its nonce properly, again by requiring Mallory to attack the client actively if she wants to run a password guessing attack. This is a common scenario: each party's nonce offers that party some protection even if another party deviates from the protocol.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to give such a detailed explanation. i am curious as to how will the server generate the nonce (random number?) and how will the server check if the nonce is correct. also the client nonce is generated by the client, how then can the server know its correct. or am i missing something?

Comment: @jiewmeng: I've expanded my initial explanation. I've also added more ways in which the nonces are useful that I had missed in my initial answer. By the way, if you're at all interested in security, I suggest you read [Ross Anderson's book](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html). It's an excellent book. For your immediate concern, see the chapter on protocols.

Comment: @Gilles hi can u explain how would a client generate a hash(snonce + cnonce + password) as mentioned in your point 3.  I mean which language would it use to generate the hash considering a Web app.

Comment: @Gilles - If you were to be certain that the client generated its nonce properly, you would not need the server nonce correct?

Comment: Just a short question: if a new `cnonce` is generated by the client on every request, how can the server verify the credentials of the client with `hash(snonce + cnonce + password)`, if the server does not now `cnonce`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira The client also sends `cnonce`.

Answer (score 5):

If the hacker got the nonce and uses it before the user does, the hacker win.
The idea behinde the nonce is that in some situations, it's hard for the hacker to steal a nonce (Typically XSRF, the nonce is protected by the same-origin-policy).
So the nonce can't protect your user if the hacker can steal a valid nonce.

Comment: In general the point of a nonce is not that the attacker can't *see* it but that the attacker can't *choose* it. Sometimes a nonce must be kept secret (e.g. a session key); then it's encrypted.

Comment: +1 Julien Parlard is correct if that hacker can use the nonce before the user, then the nonce has been defeated.

Comment: I'm still a beginner when it comes to security things, but I don't think getting server nonce before client gives hacker any advantage. He can't do anything without combining it with password. So the only thing that gives advantage to hacker would be to intercept a package WITH hash(password,nonce) and send it to the server before server receives the hash(password,nonce) from the real user. Isn't that right?