# Ajax Call Repeating on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application in asp.net using mvc. I try to send an image's bytes to the controller through a jQuery ajax request and I am encountering a problem.

When I leave a field empty and click the submit button, the message will append "please enter this field". So, the ajax request should be stopped but when I fill in this input field and click the button, the ajax request is called two times and the image is also saved in the database two times.

How can I stop this duplication?

```
if (Productname == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Product Name");
    return;
}
else if (Ratei == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Product Price");
    return;
}
else if (URLi == "") {

    alert("Please Enter Ebay Url");
    return;
}
else {
    var postdata = { ProductName: Productname, ModelID: ModelID, Rate: Ratei, Discount: Discounti, Condition: Conditioni, Url: URLi, Desc: Descriptioni, shDesc: shDescriptioni }
    var ProductId = 0;
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        // url: "/EcommerceAdmin/Admin/addProduct",
        url: "/Admin/addProduct",
        data: postdata,
        success: function (data) {
            ProductId = data.id;enter code here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're talking about is a duplicate submission.  There are a couple ways to approach that problem.

The easiest is to [disable the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button) early after you've evaluated the business rules.

A more sophisticated method is to [throttle the submission](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) so that multiple clicks are treated as a single.

The most sophisticated method is to use a [nonce (one time use code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690738/need-help-understanding-nonce) that the server can check and prevent a second submission.

And, of course, you can use multiple techniques to give a user experience while also protecting the back-end from bot-driven replays.